# How to paste text using windows paste command to other application in c#?

Tags: c#

How calling interop to paste text using windows pastse command to other application in c#?

calling interop?

i mean how to programing c# same right click to past text

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do? All standard text controls already support cut/paste operations.

Comment: i am create my application to paste text to other application how

Comment: Again, exactly what do you mean? You can select abf text, copy and paste it into another application. Please explain in detail what you want to accomplish (are you trying to use the clipboard from your program? Do you want to put some text into another application without user intervention? What _exactly?)

Comment: @Oded - it's pretty clear he wants to programatically paste text from clipboard into another application's edit controls

Comment: @Franci Penov - apologies for trying to get people to improve their questions.

Answer (score 10):

This can be a bit tricky in some scenarios, but it's actually quite simple and easy to do. Below is an example on how to get some text using a text box, (called uxData in this case), open Notepad from code, and to paste the text from the clipboard to Notepad.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

    private void OnClicked_PasteToNotepad(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // Let's start Notepad
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe";
        process.Start();

        // Give the process some time to startup
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        // Copy the text in the datafield to Clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(uxData.Text, TextDataFormat.Text);

        // Get the Notepad Handle
        IntPtr hWnd = process.Handle;

        // Activate the Notepad Window
        BringWindowToTop(hWnd);

        // Use SendKeys to Paste
        SendKeys.Send("^V");
    }
}
```

Now, say you want to paste into a *specific* field. This is where you will need to use FindWindow and FindWindowEx, to get the handle of the field you want to paste into. Here are the steps once you have copied your data to the clipboard.

1. Get the process handle
2. Bring the process into focus (Activate it)
3. Find the handle of the field you wish to paste into
4. Set focus to that field
5. Use SendKeys to paste from clipboard

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to use process.MainWindowHandle to get the BringWindowToTop to work. And for some reason I had to use a lowercase "^v" to paste (uppercase worked for notepad, but not for the program I was using). And changing it to "^{v}" seems to work much more reliable for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) class in System.Windows.Forms to inspect types of data the clipboard contains and fetch this data if needed. Clipboard in Windows holds the data "to be pasted", which can be a bitmap, text, HTML, RTF etc.

It's not quite clear what you mean by "paste". Is that "paste" supposed to happen when a button is clicked, a key is pressed or something else? Text box controls (richbox, combobox etc.) typically respond to Ctrl-V (standard Paste keystroke) and will auto-insert the text in the appropriate format (plain, RTF) from the clipboard, so you don't have to do anything manually.

In all other cases you need to decide what data you're interested in and extract it from the clipboard using appropriate [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard_members.aspx).

Comment: I believe that he's trying to take some content and programatically insert it into another application's edit controls - basically, he wants to send a Ctrl+V to that application, as far as I understand...

Comment: +1 This is better than my PInvoke answer.  Wow, you learn about new Framework classes every day...

Answer (score 0):

This is how to obtain data from the windows clipboard using P/Invoke.  That's about all I can give you without more information on what you want to paste it to.

```
 [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    static extern int OleGetClipboard([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]out object ppDataObj);

string text = ppDataObj as string;
//paste it in your application somewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get the text from right click paste**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static string GetControlV()
{
    Textbox i = new Textbox();
    i.Paste();
    return i.Text;
}
```

1. Declare a new Textbox object
2. Call it's Paste() method - Paste() is built in to the Textbox component in windows form and places the text copied from right click copy into the textbox.
3. Return the Text property of the Textbox.

You'll need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll. Just in case...
Right click in the Solution Explore "References".
Click "Add Reference".
Under the ".NET" tab you should be able to find the dll.
Then the using statment should work.